# Detecting seasonalities

Tags: time-series, forecasting, maple

I need to find some software to detect seasonalities in time-series. I have detected bi-weekly seasonality, using MAPLE, but it's only graphics without any numbers[image: The way MAPLE shows seasonality for a 1 year time-series]

I need something not only to show main seasonalities, but also to find one that can detect some sub-seasonalities and (it would be really-really awesome) calculate seasonal indexes. Or, maybe, some other way to do it, using MAPLE? I've already tried to find some software, but the main problem was, that it can calculate seasonality only if i give it a period. And I need something to find that period.

Comment: Is your data in Maple a TimeSeries object, and is this in a recent release of the product?

Comment: @acer It is an excel sheet and I download it to maple as TimeSeries object

Answer (score 0):

One way to try to find the period would be to use a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) to transform your data to the frequency domain. Then by plotting the power spectrum for the transformed data, you can find the frequency, and by extension, the period (which is equal to 1/frequency). Here's an example in Maple working with a time series of sunspot data:

https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=applications/SunspotPeriodicity